# im4j on Mac OSX not able to run commands

Tags: java, imagemagick

We have photo client program written using im4j wrapper to invoke ImageMajick to process the photo. 
The setup runs well on Windows OS , however when we run it on Mac OSX, we keep getting the following exception

```
org.im4java.core.InfoException: org.im4java.core.CommandException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "identify": error=2, No such file or directory
    at org.im4java.core.Info.getBaseInfo(Info.java:201)
    at org.im4java.core.Info.<init>(Info.java:96)
    at tenw.photos.ImageTransformer.getImageInfo(ImageTransformer.java:474)
    at tenw.photos.ImageTransformer.getCenterCoordinates(ImageTransformer.java:517)
    at tenw.photos.ImageTransformer.cropCenter(ImageTransformer.java:157)
    at tenw.photos.ImageTransformerTest.testCropCenter(ImageTransformerTest.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:154)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:127)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:118)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:208)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:203)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.JUnitTestSet.execute(JUnitTestSet.java:96)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.JUnit3Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit3Provider.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.JUnit3Provider.invoke(JUnit3Provider.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Caused by: org.im4java.core.CommandException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "identify": error=2, No such file or directory
    at org.im4java.core.ImageCommand.run(ImageCommand.java:215)
    at org.im4java.core.Info.getBaseInfo(Info.java:189)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "identify": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
    at org.im4java.process.ProcessStarter.startProcess(ProcessStarter.java:407)
    at org.im4java.process.ProcessStarter.run(ProcessStarter.java:312)
    at org.im4java.core.ImageCommand.run(ImageCommand.java:211)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:53)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:91)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:453)
```

The command identify is found in the PATH variable.
When the same command is executed on shell, it works fine. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this working  my setting path variable in eclipse's environment variable settings. Some one could enhance the answer as to why the JVM could not pick up the path variable before executing the command

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. Can you please tell me what did you add exactly in eclipse'e environment variable?